# Excel - VBA Find info among thousand of spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have around 5,200 excel spreadsheets in six different folders containing a mix of random spreadsheets and relevant sales data I need. I a need only subset of these sales data. The sales data, are custom sales proposals, made for different customers at various points in time.

First, I need to find all the spreadsheets sates data and move it to a separate folder from the other random spreadsheets. The only aspect in common from these spreadsheets is the name of the first sheet.

Once I have all the sales spreadsheets, I need to find all of those that actually used and filled accordingly (some of them are incomplete). From them I need to copy only a couple of cells that contain the name and price of the current vendor. I need to do this while keeping track of the file name and the customer name (I’d like to create a table in a worksheet with file name, customer name, competitor, price, etc.)

Then, I need to copy the actual bid offer made by our company, contained in one of two sheets of the spreadsheets. The whole workbook normally contains around 12 sheets. A complication is that the sales spreadsheets were somewhat custom made, which means the order and names of the sheets are not uniform.

I am aware that this is a complicated scenario and would greatly appreciate any feedback out there.

And please let me know if I explained the problem clearly enough.

Comment: dump all of them into some flavor of SQL and do your work from there.

Comment: I am afraid I have never used SQL...

Comment: well, it doesn't appear you've used excel much either. this not a free code writing service.

Comment: You can definitely do all of these with VBA. You should try each step one by one and show what you tried so that we can help you with it (see how to ask Questions on Stackoverflow)

Comment: Here are some keywords you'll need to do this in VBA: iterate over files in folder, iterate over worksheets, find worksheet name, index/match, pastespecial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search Excel **file contents**, using Windows Explorer's built-in ***Search*** functionality by clicking **`File Contents`** after starting the search.

[image: searchExcelFileContents]